# Create a new custom user or upate existing one

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-users

I have created a Custom user model:

```
class CUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, first_name, password,
                     is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        now = timezone.now()
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
                          first_name = first_name,
                          is_staff=is_staff, is_active=False,
                          is_superuser=is_superuser, last_login=now,
                          date_joined=now, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, first_name, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, first_name, password, False, False,
                                 **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, password, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, first_name, password, True, True,
                                 **extra_fields)


class CUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=254, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff status'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin '
                    'site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether this user should be treated as '
                    'active. Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'))
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(_('last updated'), default=timezone.now)
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to= generate_random_filename,
                                processors=[ResizeToFill(640, 640)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 60})

    objects = CUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            this = CUser.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.image != self.image:
                this.image.delete()
        except: pass
        super(CUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My regisration serializer:

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'},
                                     write_only=True,
                                     validators=settings.get('PASSWORD_VALIDATORS'))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = tuple(User.REQUIRED_FIELDS) + (
            User.USERNAME_FIELD,
            'image',
            'password',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        if settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
                user.is_active = False
                user.save(update_fields=['is_active'])
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        return user
```

My registration view:

```
class RegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserRegistrationSerializer
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.AllowAny,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save()
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__, user=user, request=self.request)
        if settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
            self.send_activation_email(user)
        elif settings.get('SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL'):
            self.send_confirmation_email(user)
```

This creates a new user. But, when I try to hit this endpoint with some already registered email, I get an error. Instead of this, I want to update the user entry in case the user is not active and wants to register again. I am unable to figure this out. I tried using the update() method in the serializer but it diddn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this inside the serializer's `create` method.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=validated_data['email'])
        // There was already a user with that email, do something
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        if settings.get('SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL'):
            with transaction.atomic():
                user.is_active = False
                user.save(update_fields=['is_active'])

    return user
```

Comment: I tried adding it but I still get "user with this email address already exists." I tried putting print statements in view's perform_create() and serializer create(). For a non existent email both statements get printed but, for an existent email none of them does.

Comment: Could you add this error's traceback in your question?

Comment: There is no error. "user with this email address already exists."  is the response returned with a 400 status code.

Comment: Oh yes, your model has a `unique=True` constraint, so your serializer validates against that before reaching the `create` method. Try adding `queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)` to your `RegistrationView` and see if the validation error still occurs.

Comment: I am still getting the same response. Could you please explain why are you expecting this to work after changing the queryset to this?